# Stripe token not generating when using a live Publiashable Key

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am building a custom checkout where Stripe is handling the payment information. I'm using the Stripe Elements Library. When I was using the test publishable key I was about to get an input with a token but once I switched to the live key that was no longer happening. I'm not sure if there something missing in my setup that's not allowing the token to be generated when the live key is active.

Here's my Javascript for the Stripe Elements integrations

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script>
// Create a Stripe client.
var stripe = Stripe('pk_live_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

// Create an instance of Elements.
var elements = stripe.elements();

// Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
// (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
var style = {
    base: {
        color: '#32325d',
        fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
        fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
        fontSize: '16px',
        '::placeholder': {
        color: '#aab7c4'
        },
        ':focus': {
            color: '#333',
        },

        '::placeholder': {
            color: '#333',
        },

        ':focus::placeholder': {
            color: '#333',
        },
    },
    invalid: {
        color: '#DC5B5B',
        iconColor: '#DC5B5B',
        ':focus': {
            color: '#DC5B5B',
        },
        '::placeholder': {
            color: '#DC5B5B',
        },
    }
};
                
var elementClasses = {
    focus: 'focus',
    empty: 'empty',
    invalid: 'invalid',
};

// Create an instance of the card Element.
var cardNumber = elements.create('cardNumber', {
    style: style,
    classes: elementClasses,
});
cardNumber.mount('#example3-card-number');

var cardExpiry = elements.create('cardExpiry', {
    style: style,
    classes: elementClasses,
});
cardExpiry.mount('#example3-card-expiry');

var cardCvc = elements.create('cardCvc', {
    style: style,
    classes: elementClasses,
});
cardCvc.mount('#example3-card-cvc');

registerElements([cardNumber, cardExpiry, cardCvc], 'example3');    
                
    function registerElements(elements, exampleName) {
        var formClass = '.' + exampleName;
        var example = document.querySelector(formClass);
        var form = example.querySelector('form');
        var resetButton = example.querySelector('a.reset');
        var error = form.querySelector('.error');
        var errorMessage = error.querySelector('.message');

        function enableInputs() {
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(
              form.querySelectorAll(
                "input[type='text'], input[type='email'], input[type='tel']"
              ),
              function(input) {
                input.removeAttribute('disabled');
              }
            );
        }
        function disableInputs() {
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(
                form.querySelectorAll(
                    "input[type='text'], input[type='email'], input[type='tel']"
                ),
                 function(input) {
                    input.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
                 }
            );
        }
        function triggerBrowserValidation() {
            // The only way to trigger HTML5 form validation UI is to fake a user submit
            // event.
            var submit = document.createElement('input');
            submit.type = 'submit';
            submit.style.display = 'none';
            form.appendChild(submit);
            submit.click();
            submit.remove();
        }
                
        // Listen for errors from each Element, and show error messages in the UI.
        var savedErrors = {};
                
        elements.forEach(function(element, idx) {
            element.on('change', function(event) {
                if (event.error) {
                        error.classList.add('visible');
                        savedErrors[idx] = event.error.message;
                        errorMessage.innerText = event.error.message;
                } else {
                    savedErrors[idx] = null;

                    // Loop over the saved errors and find the first one, if any.
                    var nextError = Object.keys(savedErrors)
                        .sort()
                        .reduce(function(maybeFoundError, key) {
                            return maybeFoundError || savedErrors[key];
                        }, null);
                      
                    error.classList.remove('visible');

                    if (nextError) {
                        // Now that they've fixed the current error, show another one.
                        errorMessage.innerText = nextError;
                        error.classList.add('visible');
                    } else {
                        // The user fixed the last error; no more errors.
                        error.classList.remove('visible');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
                
        // Listen on the form's 'submit' handler...
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            // Trigger HTML5 validation UI on the form if any of the inputs fail
            // validation.
            var plainInputsValid = true;
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(form.querySelectorAll('input'), function(
                input
            ) {
                 if (input.checkValidity && !input.checkValidity()) {
                    plainInputsValid = false;
                    return;
                }
            });
            if (!plainInputsValid) {
                triggerBrowserValidation();
                 return;
            }

            // Show a loading screen...
            example.classList.add('submitting');

            // Disable all inputs.
            disableInputs();

            // Gather additional customer data we may have collected in our form.
            var name = form.querySelector('#' + exampleName + '-name');
            var address1 = form.querySelector('#' + exampleName + '-address');
            var city = form.querySelector('#' + exampleName + '-city');
            var state = form.querySelector('#' + exampleName + '-state');
            var zip = form.querySelector('#' + exampleName + '-zip');
            var additionalData = {
                name: name ? name.value : undefined,
                address_line1: address1 ? address1.value : undefined,
                address_city: city ? city.value : undefined,
                address_state: state ? state.value : undefined,
                address_zip: zip ? zip.value : undefined,
            };

            // Use Stripe.js to create a token. We only need to pass in one Element
            // from the Element group in order to create a token. We can also pass
            // in the additional customer data we collected in our form.
            stripe.createToken(elements[0], additionalData).then(function(result) {
              // Stop loading!
              example.classList.remove('submitting');
              if (result.token) {
                stripeTokenHandler(result.token)
              } else {
                // Otherwise, un-disable inputs.
                enableInputs();
              }
            });
        });
                
    }
            
// Submit the form with the token ID.
function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
    // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
    var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
}
```

I only made minor changes to the Javascript code above to match my html when I first implemented it other than that the code is exactly what I found and used when I had the test key.

I'm not very familar with Stripe's Element Library so any help would be greatly appreciated.